# How to find an expression with an unknown number of letters in the bash?

Tags: command-line, bash

How do I match a phrase with an unknown number of letters in the bash

I have these lines.

```
This is a line **s838e**
This is a line **s9e**
```

I want grep to return any line that contains a statement with such a syntax، but the number of numbers in the middle of the expression is unknown. How do I do that?

this expression: SUnknown_number_of_numbersE

Should I use another tool?

If you don't understand my question، I'm sorry، my English is so bad.

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your code like this:

```bash
phrase='This is a line **s838e**'
```

You could make a test like this:

```bash
if [[ "$phrase" =~ ^This\ is\ a\ line\ \*\*s[0-9]+e\*\*$ ]]; then
    echo "match"
else
    echo "not match"
fi
```

If french is your mother tongue, you could read this page: https://fr.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programmation_Bash/Regex